# Display city names in English regardless of location with Google Maps API

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

How do I display the names of cities (as well as roads and natural reserves, if possible) in English in all countries on a Google Map displayed using the Google Maps API V3?

Up to this point, I've been able to partly achieve my result through appending the parameter `language=en`, yielding the result presented in the image below:

[image: Google Maps with added parameters sensor and language]

This gets me half the way. What I would like to achieve is to completely hide the non-English names, and only display city names in English (e.g. to display `Münich` instead of `München`).

Is this even possible? If it is, I would greatly appreciate if someone could guide me towards the solution.

Answer (score 0):

Use This:

```
function initMap() {
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
        center: {
            lat: -33.8688,
            lng: 151.2195
        },
        zoom: 13
    });
    var input = /** @type {!HTMLInputElement} */ (
        document.getElementById('pac-input'));

    var types = document.getElementById('type-selector');
    map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_LEFT].push(input);
    map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_LEFT].push(types);

    var autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input);
    autocomplete.bindTo('bounds', map);

    var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        map: map,
        anchorPoint: new google.maps.Point(0, -29)
    });

    autocomplete.addListener('place_changed', function() {
        infowindow.close();
        marker.setVisible(false);
        var place = autocomplete.getPlace();
        if (!place.geometry) {
            window.alert("Autocomplete's returned place contains no geometry");
            return;
        }

        // If the place has a geometry, then present it on a map.
        if (place.geometry.viewport) {
            map.fitBounds(place.geometry.viewport);
        } else {
            map.setCenter(place.geometry.location);
            map.setZoom(17); // Why 17? Because it looks good.
        }
        marker.setIcon( /** @type {google.maps.Icon} */ ({
            url: place.icon,
            size: new google.maps.Size(71, 71),
            origin: new google.maps.Point(0, 0),
            anchor: new google.maps.Point(17, 34),
            scaledSize: new google.maps.Size(35, 35)
        }));
        marker.setPosition(place.geometry.location);
        marker.setVisible(true);

        var address = '';
        if (place.address_components) {
            address = [
                (place.address_components[0] && place.address_components[0].short_name || ''), (place.address_components[1] && place.address_components[1].short_name || ''), (place.address_components[2] && place.address_components[2].short_name || '')
            ].join(' ');
        }

        infowindow.setContent('<div><strong>' + place.name + '</strong><br>' + address);
        infowindow.open(map, marker);
    });
```

Comment: Thank you Anil! I cannot seem to make sense how your solution relates to my question. I do neither want to use an input for autocompletion, place additional markers, or to use InfoWindows. Would you mind explaining a bit further what I am not seeing?

Comment: Hey @anil-samal ! As you probably understand, most of the code is redundant for the example (e.g. only showing labels at different levels of zoom, custom styles, how the markers are generated, etc). Hence, I will here include the code for initiating the map object.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/NUQJQ0vd Tell me if you need to some some other parts of the code - however, I do not believe that my code is relevant to the question I am asking, as it's quite a binary feature - either it works (e.g. with a flag enabled), or the code does nothing to make it work. It's not a bug in the code, as I do not know where to start to add the feature.

Comment: Hi @Wilhelmw posting another simple example hope this will work for you

Comment: Here the jsbin link hope it will solve your problem https://jsfiddle.net/anil56samal/my8um8jq/